# Can $z$ still be called "limit" when at some point $f(x)=z$?

Tags: limits, functions

For the function:

$f(x) = {(x-1)^3 - (x+2)^3 \over (x+1)^2+2x+3}$ with $x \geq 1$

I have calculated that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = -3 $

My question is: Can you call $-3$ the **limit** of function $f$, although $f(1)=-3$ ?

[image: Plot]

Comment: Short answer: Yes you can.

Comment: Whenever you're uncertain of something like this, you need to go back and look up the **definition** of limit and see what that has to say about it.